# Writing plain text to an NFC tag, problems with intents

Tags: java, android, android-intent, nfc

I'm trying to make an application that writes a simple plain text message to an NFC tag. The user writes a message in the EditText box, then on button press, the app writes the text onto a tag.
I've been following this tutorial: http://www.framentos.com/it/android-tutorial/2012/07/31/write-hello-world-into-a-nfc-tag-with-a/
However, when i try to put the NFC tag up next to it, the phone opens up another app, instead of using mine that is already open. I know the problem's with the intents, but i don't want to declare the intent filter in the manifest, because i don't want the app to open up when the tag is placed next to the phone, i want the app to be already open beforehand.
Here's the code for the application:

```
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.nfc.FormatException;
import android.nfc.NdefMessage;
import android.nfc.NdefRecord;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.nfc.tech.Ndef;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    NfcAdapter adapter;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    IntentFilter writeTagFilters[];
    Tag mytag;
    Context ctx;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ctx=this;
        Button btnWrite = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        final EditText message = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        btnWrite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    if(mytag==null){
                        Toast.makeText(ctx, ctx.getString(R.string.error_detected), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{
                        write(message.getText().toString(),mytag);
                        Toast.makeText(ctx, ctx.getString(R.string.ok_writing), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(ctx, ctx.getString(R.string.error_writing), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (FormatException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(ctx, ctx.getString(R.string.error_writing) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        adapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
        IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
        tagDetected.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        writeTagFilters = new IntentFilter[] { tagDetected };
    }

    private NdefRecord createRecord(String text) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        //create the message in according with the standard
        String lang = "en";
        byte[] textBytes = text.getBytes();
        byte[] langBytes = lang.getBytes("US-ASCII");
        int langLength = langBytes.length;
        int textLength = textBytes.length;

        byte[] payload = new byte[1 + langLength + textLength];
        payload[0] = (byte) langLength;

        // copy langbytes and textbytes into payload
        System.arraycopy(langBytes, 0, payload, 1, langLength);
        System.arraycopy(textBytes, 0, payload, 1 + langLength, textLength);

        NdefRecord recordNFC = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN, NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT, new byte[0], payload);
        return recordNFC;
    }

    private void write(String text, Tag tag) throws IOException, FormatException {

        NdefRecord[] records = { createRecord(text) };
        NdefMessage message = new NdefMessage(records);
        Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
        ndef.connect();
        ndef.writeNdefMessage(message);
        ndef.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
        if(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())){
            mytag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
            Toast.makeText(this, this.getString(R.string.ok_detection) + mytag.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {


   return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Please help, i don't know what i'm doing wrong!
I'm just a beginner at NFC and Android programming!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use enable forground dispatch : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html#foreground-dispatch

> The foreground dispatch system allows an activity to intercept an
>   intent and claim priority over other activities that handle the same
>   intent.

**UPDATE1**

It's difficult to write on all kind of tags, some of them have closed specifications. You could start by writing on [Ndef](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/Ndef.html) and [NdefFormatable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/NdefFormatable.html) tags.

For instance:

```
@Override 
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
}

@Override 
protected void onResume(){
  super.onResume();
  PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,new Intent(this,getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP),0);
  IntentFilter ndef=new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
  try {
    ndef.addDataType("*/*");
  }
 catch (  MalformedMimeTypeException e) {
    Log.e(TAG,"Bad MIME type declared",e);
    return;
  }
  IntentFilter[] filters=new IntentFilter[]{ndef};
  String[][] techLists=new String[][]{new String[]{Ndef.class.getName()},new String[]{NdefFormatable.class.getName()}};
  mNfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this,pendingIntent,filters,techLists);
}

@Override 
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
    String[] techList = tag.getTechList();
    for (String tech : techList) {
          if (tech.equals(Ndef.class.getName())) {
              //write NDEF msg
          } else if (tech.equals(NdefFormatable.class.getName())) {
              //format and write NDEF msg
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm still having problems. It gives me a nullpointer exception, int the onResume function. I think it's because of the techListArrays, because i don't know how to use that or what to put in it :(

Comment: Alright, i kinda fixed it using code from this: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reading-nfc-tags-with-android--mobile-17278

Thanks alot!!

Comment: You could NDEF http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/Ndef.html in your tech list. You'll get only already NDEF formatted TAG.

Comment: What if i want to write on all sorts of tags though? how can i do that? do i have to create a techlist file in my res folder? and how do i implement that in my code afterwards?